# Window.print is showing tablet view in print promt in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular

For print functionality am using the window.print() and displaying the view on page which I want to display. But once print prompt opened then its is taking tablet view in the print prompt. I want to print content which is on desktop but as there is different view for Tablet it's showing tablet view in Print prompt.

Can you please suggest what will be the approach to display desktop page in print prompt.

Comment: Which browser are you attempting this on and what are the window dimensions when you go to print? If a Angular detects a window width below a certain threshold, it might default to tablet view because of how reactive sites tend to work.

Comment: Am doing it for Chrome browser. Not settings any windows dimension when i go to print. Default window is taking to 768px. Need to know how can I increase window dimension when i go to print so that it won't take 768px view.

Comment: Can you post the code/directive you're using to print with?

Comment: Sorry code is really complex to post here.I want to get the thought of how we can change window dimension when we go to print.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what the print interface looks like? Have you tested it on any other devices to see if it does the same thing? window.print() doesn't appear to take any additional arguments, which means the issue must either be with the code itself or with the device it's being used on.

Comment: It's got resolved but for IE having some issue.      media print { page { size:330mm 427mm}}